# LinkedIn REST API: Throttle Limit for resource 'Search People' reached at 409 of 100k

Tags: api, rest, limit, linkedin-api, throttling

I have a program that searches LinkedIn members by their first and last names, for academic research purposes.

I have a LinkedIn developer account that is supposed to have 100k calls to the relevant 'Search People' resource per day, but at only 400+ (see stats below) the API call throws exceptions, saying that "Throttle limit for calls to this resource is reached".

How is this possible where my limit is so much higher?

--

LinkedIn statistics from their website:

API Usage Report for  beginning 23 Jan 2013 midnight UTC till now

Resource: Search People

Usage:
Call Count: 409
Allowed: 100000

Status: OK (green tick)

Throttled Members: 1 (List of Throttled Members for Search People: Idb_YiFpOs)

Answer (score 5):

The total application limit is 100K, that's right. But there is also a user limit, and a developer limit, where the limit for the developer is 400 calls per 24 hours, this is why you're being throttled.

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits , check the "People Search" section.

Comment: Scraping is a better option?

Comment: Scraping is against the Linkedin TOS, and will get you into a lot of trouble with them.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while but the stats suggest people still look at this and I'm experimenting with the LinkedIn API and can provide some more detail.

The typical throttles are stated as both a max (e.g. 100K) and a per-user-token number (e.g. 500). Those numbers together mean you can get up to a maximum of 100,000 calls per day to the API but even as a developer a single user token means a maximum of 500 per day. So that would imply you need 200 users to reach the full quota.

I ran into this, and after setting up the beginnings of an app and getting some users I can confirm there are more *total* calls allowed. [Removed discussion of what was possibly an accidental backdoor in the LinkedIn API.]

Comment: Hi, what is the difference in both, I am trying to access the LinkedIn data via script. Now how can I send the query as application and not as individual.

Comment: As of last I heard they changed the process of getting an application API key and you have to apply through LinkedIn pertnership programs https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs  It used to be just an easy online sign up but they did away with that as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

For share in linkedin

***Throttle Limits***

**Throttle Type              Daily Call Limit (UTC)**

Application maximum =         25,000

Per individual user =          25

Per individual developer =     100